# Regular expression optional matching

Tags: regex, perl

I have a few strings in an array that are of this pattern:

```
Aaaaa
Bbbbb (Ccccc)
Ddddd
Eeeee
Fffff (Ggggg)
```

and I want to make a new array that looks like this:

```
Aaaaa
Bbbbb
Ddddd
Eeeee
Fffff
```

I am able to match the pattern that has the parentheses with the following Perl regex:

```
$string =~ /(.*?)(\(.*?\))/;
push(@newarray, $1);
```

But that will not work for those strings without the text in the parantheses. I have tried a few others to match the optional parantheses, but none seem to work:

```
$string =~ /(.*?)(?:\(.*?\))/;
$string =~ /(.*?)(\(.*?\))?/;
$string =~ /(.*?)(?:\(.*?\))?/;
```

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for is:

```
/^(.*?)(?: \(.*\))?\z/
```

Your last two would work if you added `\z`. The problem is that `.*?` is happily matching zero characters.

---

Solutions:

```
my @b = @a;
s/ \(.*\)// for @b;
```

or

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( apply );
my @b = apply { s/ \(.*\)// } @a;
```

or (5.14+)

```
my @b = map s/ \(.*\)//r, @a;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are never any spaces in the initial string then you can write just

```
my @newarray = map /^(\S+)/, @array;
```

If it may contain spaces, then

```
my @newarray = map /^([^(]*[^\s(])/, @array;
```